# What is a "multicharge nuclei"?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, charge, baryons, color-charge

When doing some reading on particle physics, I came across the concept of a "multicharge nuclei". A Google search of this phrase returns a number of research papers, but no definition for what a "multicharge nuclei" is.

How does it make sense to say that a nuclei can have multiple charges (that is, a "multicharge nuclei")? I recently read about the concepts of [baryonic charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number) and [color charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge). In the context of color charge, if I understood the theory correctly, the particles in the nucleus must have a color charge of $0$, right? So is it referring to "baryonic charge"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this for a novice.

Comment: Source for where you came across the term?

Comment: @probably_someone I can't remember now. I was reading about some other particle physics material (about collisions, if I remember correctly), and then I encountered this term. I think this might be referring to it https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293616516_Effect_of_heavy_multicharge_nuclei_on_materials_and_elements_of_space_equipment

Comment: In this context, it almost certainly just means nuclei that have an electric charge of 2+, 3+, 4+, etc., counting any electrons that may be orbiting them. Notice how the multicharged nuclei in question were fission fragments from californium-242 (i.e. other, ordinary nuclei).

Comment: @probably_someone Ohh, yes, now I think I remember: It had something to do with "multicharge nuclei" being able to capture more electrons in collisions with matter. Given what you've just said, it makes sense that a 2+, 3+, 4+, etc., nuclei would be able to capture more electrons than a 1+ charge nuclei (since the nuclei have a greater positive charge, creating greater attraction of the negatively charged electrons). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is used in cosmic ray experiments, describing the composition of the flux:

> [Of primary cosmic rays,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Composition) which originate outside of Earth's atmosphere, about 99% are the nuclei of well-known atoms *(stripped of their electron shells),* and about 1% are solitary electrons (similar to beta particles). Of the nuclei, about 90% are simple protons (i.e., hydrogen nuclei); 9% are alpha particles, identium nuclei; and 1% are the nuclei of heavier elements, called HZE ions. These fractions vary highly over the energy range of cosmic rays.

*italics mine*

You will find this expression, [if you can get access, here .](https://www.jstor.org/stable/74489?seq=1)

It is to separate classic "rays" in nuclear physics, alpha beta and gamma, with stripped nuclei in cosmic rays, i.e. nuclei different from protons and helium.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this is essentially what probably_someone said in the comments, except for 3+, 4+, 5+, etc. (excluding the 2+), since 2+ is the helium nucleus?

Comment: Yes , alphas are in the regular nuclear rays.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.